# How can I disable color highlighting and marks of versioning in NetBeans?

Tags: mercurial, netbeans, syntax-highlighting, highlighting, versioning

How can I disable color highlighting and marks of versioning in NetBeans? (in my case, mercurial)
PS: Now that I see, highlighting is on html tag attribute values, and doesn't respond to versioning, but it's also a little annoying and can't find out where to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Tools >> Options >> Fonts & Colors`
On the `Syntax` tab, language `HTML` (or `XHTML`), `'Parameter Value'`, `Background`

If that doesn't work, try the `Versioning` tab, `Mercurial` and modify your `Highlighting` settings there.